# How to filter elements returned by QuerySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript library, and I use this function to match elements:

```
$ = function (a)
{
    var x;
    if (typeof a !== "string" || typeof a === "undefined"){ return a;}
    
    //Pick the quickest method for each kind of selector
    if(a.match(/^#([\w\-]+$)/))
    {
        return document.getElementById(a.split('#')[1]);
    }
    else if(a.match(/^([\w\-]+)$/))
    {
        x = document.getElementsByTagName(a);
    }
    else
    {
        x = document.querySelectorAll(a);
    }
    
    //Return the single object if applicable
    return (x.length === 1) ? x[0] : x;
};
```

There are occasions where I would want to filter the result of this function, like pick out a `div span`, or a `#id div` or some other fairly simple selector.

How can I filter these results? Can I create a document fragment, and use the querySelectorAll method on that fragment, or do I have to resort to manual string manipulation?

I only care about modern browsers and IE8+.

If you want to look at the rest of my library, it's here: https://github.com/timw4mail/kis-js

Edit:

To clarify, I want to be able to do something like $_(selector).children(other_selector) and return the children elements matching that selector.

Edit:

So here's my potential solution to the simplest selectors:

```
tag_reg = /^([\w\-]+)$/;
id_reg = /#([\w\-]+$)/;
class_reg = /\.([\w\-]+)$/;

function _sel_filter(filter, curr_sel)
{
    var i,
        len = curr_sel.length,
        matches = [];
    
    if(typeof filter !== "string")
    {
        return filter;
    }

    //Filter by tag
    if(filter.match(tag_reg))
    {
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(curr_sell[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == filter.toLowerCase())
            {
                matches.push(curr_sel[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(filter.match(class_reg))
    {
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(curr_sel[i].classList.contains(filter))
            {
                matches.push(curr_sel[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(filter.match(id_reg))
    {
        return document.getElementById(filter);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(filter+" is not a valid filter");
    }
    
    return (matches.length === 1) ? matches[0] : matches;
    
}
```

It takes a tag like `div`, an id, or a class selector, and returns the matching elements with the `curr_sel` argument.

I don't want to have to resort to a full selector engine, so is there a better way?

Comment: Apart from educational purposes why is your library better then existing ones?

Comment: @Raynos I'm trying to create a minimalistic, modular library that doesn't have to deal with the stupidities of JScript in IE6/7

Comment: I guess that's pretty unique. Most libraries deal with IE6/7.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't think I get the question right. Why would you want to "filter" the result of `querySelectorAll()` which infact, is some kind of a filter itself. If you query for `div span` or even better `#id div`, those results are already filtered, no ?

However, you can apply `Array.prototype.filter` to the static result of `querySelectorAll` like follows:

```
var filter   = Array.prototype.filter,
    result   = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
    filtered = filter.call( result, function( node ) {
        return !!node.querySelectorAll('span').length;
    });
```

That code would first use `querySelectorAll()` to query for all `<div>` nodes within the document. Afterwards it'll filter for `<div>` nodes which contain at least one `<span>`. That code doesn't make much sense and is just for demonstrative purposes (just in case some SO member wants to create a donk comment)

**update**

You can also filter with `Element.compareDocumentPosition`. I'll also tell if Elements are `disconnected`, `following`, `preceding`, or `contained`. See [MDC .compareDocumentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.compareDocumentPosition)

Comment: Sometimes I need to get the parent or children of the current element.

Comment: Does an element list/node list always inherit from the Array prototype?

Comment: Hmm...that's helpful, but then I still have to have the node to compare with.

Comment: Well, a possible use could be to have multiple different Selectors (simply because the DOM is different), but then you still want to clean those elements from a certain elements, which are always present.

Of course, this looks like, something went wrong in the architecture in the first place, but we all have been there...

Comment: Thanks this answer made me realise I should filter using the querySelector instead of filtering the selection twice.

Answer (score 38):

> Note: NodeList is not a genuine array, that is to say it doesn't have
>   the array methods like slice, some, map etc. To convert it into an
>   array, try Array.from(nodeList).

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

for example:

```
let highlightedItems = Array.from(userList.querySelectorAll(".highlighted"));

highlightedItems.filter((item) => {
 //...
})
```

Answer (score 18):

Most concise way in 2019 is with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` plus an array literal `[...]`, which work great with iterable objects like the NodeList returned by `querySelectorAll`:

`[...document.querySelectorAll(".myClass")].filter(el=>{/*your code here*/})`

Comment: Looks like a beautiful but expensive way to do it though (in older browsers).

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers that support `qsa` also support a non-standard `matchesSelector` method, like:

```
element.webkitMatchesSelector('.someSelector')
```

...that will return a boolean representing whether `element` matched the selector provided. So you could iterate the collection, and apply that method, retaining positive results.

In browsers that don't have a `matchesSelector`, you'd probably need to build your own selector based method similar to the selector engine you're building.

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to avoid browser-specific functions.

Comment: @timw4mail: Yes, but you could test for the existence of the browser-specific ones, and use it if available, or use your engine if not. If you tried to use a temporary container like a fragment, you'd need to remove the element from its location, and place it inside. Probably not what you want.

Comment: @Raynos: :o) It's pretty new. I heard about it when reading one of the jQuery release notes. I think they said they lobbied for it.

Comment: From [1.4.3 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/) *"The jQuery project petitioned the browsers to add the new matchesSelector method (writing up a test suite, talking with vendors, and filing bugs) and the whole community gets to reap the excellent performance benefits now."*

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array methods.

For example, ".myClass" is set on input elements and you want to return all inputs where value is not empty. You can use this:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".myClass")).filter( el => el.value !== "")
```