# Equivalent of contents().filter() in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, equivalent

I have this bit of JQuery code I need to rewrite in Vanilla JS.

```
$('#myID :not(a, span)').contents().filter(
function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 && this.data.trim().length > 0;})
.wrap('<span class="mySpanClass" />');
```

I've tried this;

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myID  :not(a), #myID :not(span)'), 
function(el, i){
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.setAttribute('class', 'rvReaderContent');
    while((el.firstChild) && (el.firstChild.nodeType === 3) && (el.firstChild.data.trim().length > 0)){
       var textNode = el.firstChild
      el.insertBefore(span, textNode);
      span.appendChild(textNode);   
    }
});
```

I've tried other variants but nothing seems to work. I can't find a substitute for JQuery's contents() method.

Would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter elements returned by QuerySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791112/how-to-filter-elements-returned-by-queryselectorall)

Comment: Hi. Have checked the suggested article and it doesn't seem to answer my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it into an array with `Array.from` and then use Array's `filter` function:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#myID  :not(a), #myID :not(span)'))
    .filter(function(el) { ... })
    .forEach(function(el) { ... });
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to figure it by tinkering with your suggestion.

Comment: Cool, I'm happy to help. You can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla JavaScript solution. You can check the comments for logic behind the code:

```js
document.querySelector('#formatBtn').addEventListener('click', format);

function format() {
  //Apply your query selector to get the elements
  var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('#myID :not(a):not(span)');

  //Turn NodeList to Array and filter it
  var html = Array.from(nodeList)
    .filter(el => el.textContent.trim().length > 0)
    .reduce((accum, el) => {
      //Wrap the textContent in your tag
      accum += `<span class="mySpanClass">${el.textContent}</span>`;
      return accum;
    }, '');
  //Update the HTML
  document.getElementById('formattedHtml').innerHTML = html;
  //Remove other stuff
  document.querySelector('#myID').remove();
  document.querySelector('#formatBtn').remove();
}
```

```css
.mySpanClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myID">
  <a href="#">Some link</a>
  <p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
  <p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
  <span id="s1">Span 1</span>
</div>

<div id="formattedHtml"></div>

<input id="formatBtn" type="button" value="Format HTML">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't do much for my immediate problem but it made me look up and appreciate the Array.prototype.filter method. I also learned how to fix my selector from your snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out;

This was my solution;

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#myID :not(a):not(span)'), function(el){
    Array.from(el.childNodes, function(ch){
        if(ch.nodeType === 3 && ch.data.trim().length > 0){
           var span = document.createElement('span');
           span.setAttribute('class', 'mySpanClass');
           el.insertBefore(span, ch);
           span.appendChild(ch);
       }
   });
 });
```

Thanks @ttulka for your input. It led me in the right direction.