# How to filter querySelectorAll results?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a nested table of contents by extracting h2,h3,h4, and h5 tags from the page.
So I've written this:

```
var enterycontent = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content")[0]
var htags = enterycontent.querySelectorAll('h2,h3,h4,h5');
var ul = document.getElementById("table_of_contents");

for (i = 0; i < htags.length; i++) {
  var nhs = htags[i];
  htags[i].setAttribute("id", "htag" + i);
  var innerhtag = nhs.innerText;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  ul.appendChild(li);
  var hrefid = '#htag' + i;
  li.innerHTML = ('<a href="#htag' + i + '">' + innerhtag + '</a>');
}
```

It works great. But I wanted to add one more thing, so I tried to **add a "child" class** to the h3,h4,h5 tags and a **"parent" class** to h2 tags.
I've tried to use .includes function but it doesn't work.

```
if(nhs.includes("h2")) {
//css adding rules...
}
```

How can I filter querySelectorAll results and add an **IF condition** for adding "child" and "parent" css classes?

Comment: Please post the minimal amount of code to reproduce your issue. This includes the needed html code.

Comment: @MarkBaijens it's simply using the default WordPress content HTML markup.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve].  In this case, the jquery doc.ready doesn't seem remotely relevant to the question and should be removed; leaving no jquery at all so that tag can be removed.

Comment: "*It's **simply** using the WordPress...*" - nowhere in your question/tags does it mention "wordpress".  We're not mind readers.

Comment: @freedomn-m I've edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nodeName` in order to check the type of an element. So in you case, this would work.

```
if (nhs.nodeName === "H2") { 
    // Do something
}
```

So as to use your code, it would end up looking something like the following.

```
for (i = 0; i < htags.length; i++) {
  var nhs = htags[i];
  htags[i].setAttribute("id", "htag" + i);
  var innerhtag = nhs.innerText;
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  ul.appendChild(li);
  var hrefid = '#htag' + i;
  li.innerHTML = ('<a href="#htag' + i + '" target="_blank" data-localscroll="true">' + innerhtag + '</a>');
  if (nhs.nodeName === "H2") {
      // Do something
  } else if (nhs.nodeName === "H3" || nhs.nodeName === "H4" || nhs.nodeName === "H5") {
      // Do something else
  }
}
```

**Important** `nodeName` will return the element's type in capital letters, so checking for `h2` won't work, you need to check for `H2`.

Comment: @MostafaSafarian glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple possibility.

> Note: NodeList is not a genuine array, that is to say it doesn't have the array methods like slice, some, map etc. To convert it into an array, try Array.from(nodeList). (cf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791112/how-to-filter-elements-returned-by-queryselectorall))

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

for example:

```
    let htags = userList.querySelectorAll(".h1...");

    let htagsArray= Array.from(htags);

    htagsArray.filter((item) => {
     //...
    })
```

Or you can simply add class to your html element and do :

```
If (htags[1].classList.contain("h2") {
   // Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop trough the elements with `forEach` and assign the desired class. You can use the tagName property to get the elements name.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h2,h3,h4,h5').forEach((el) => {
  var newClass = el.tagName === 'H2' ? "parent" : 'child';
  el.classList.add(newClass);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
}

.child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
<h4>h4</h4>
<h5>h5</h5>
```